# Can I store a MATLAB slice in a variable?

Tags: matlab, slice

I have a lengthy slice sequence that I need to apply to lots of MATLAB matrices. How can I do this?

i.e. can I simplify,

```
y(1:some_var*3,1:some_other_var*3,1:another_var*3) = x1(1:some_var*3,1:some_other_var*3,1:another_var*3) .* x2(1:some_var*3,1:some_other_var*3,1:another_var*3) ./ x3(1:some_var*3,1:some_other_var*3,1:another_var*3)
```

to something like,

```
inds = slice(1:some_var*3,1:some_other_var*3,1:another_var*3)
y(inds) = x1(inds) .* x2(inds) ./ x3(inds)
```

like I can do in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to store each vector of indices in a cell of a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html), then extract the cell array content as a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html) like so:

```
inds = {1:some_var*3, 1:some_other_var*3, 1:another_var*3};
y(inds{:}) = x1(inds{:}) .* x2(inds{:}) ./ x3(inds{:});
```

If you have large matrices, with relatively small/sparse sets of indices, this *may* be more efficient than [using a logical mask as Amro suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819395/can-i-store-a-matlab-slice-in-a-variable/6819551#6819551).

Comment: I chose this as the answer since it is possible with line of preparation and demonstrated some pretty interesting MATLAB-fu with generating comma separated lists with cell arrays.

Comment: Is tehre a way to use the `end` operator using this technique?

Comment: @Brendan: Unfortunately, you won't be able to use the [`end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/end.html) keyword within any of the expressions in the cell array `inds`. However, if you want to index all the elements of a given dimension, you can put the single character string `':'` in the corresponding cell.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you can create a logical mask:

```
%# assuming x1,x2,x3,y are all of the same size

mask = false(size(x1));
mask(1:some_var*3,1:some_other_var*3,1:another_var*3) = true;

y(mask) = x1(mask).*x2(mask)./x3(mask);
```

Other functions that you might want to read about: [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html), [SUB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html)